# How Do I insert data into multiple different tables within one form in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I created a form design in microsoft Access and next to the spots where I want to enter data, I drew text boxes. How do I link each text box to a specific key in a table?

It appears as though I can only link the form to one table. This is what my form looks like: [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OchL9.png)

Comment: two suggestions.  First try hooking up the table relationships under Database tools-relationships.  Then use one of the create forms wizards.  Examine how access creates forms for multiple related tables.  Otherwise add a button to your form and in its on click event save the various fields of your form to the appropriate tables.

Comment: That's a big, busy form. Ever consider organizing with a tab control? Normally, a form is used to enter/edit records for a single table. That's why form/subforms is common structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, are the box(s) you drawn on the right side of a form belong to a different table? And VERY important, are those records related to the current form's one main record?

You can certainly have multiple tables in a form, and this is achieved by using sub-forms for the other tables.

So, each of your sections on the right side can be bound to another table. You do this by building separate forms for those additional box(s) you have. You then open up the main form in design mode, and then drag + drop in the additional forms into that one main form.

Of course, those additional forms can be bound to a different table, and you setup the relationship(s) to the one main form by using the link master, and link child settings of the so-called sub form control.

So, say I have a table called "People".

And I wanted to display a hotel they are booked to.

So, I build a form, bound to the People table.

Then, I build a form for the hotels.

Then, I open up the form People in design mode, and I drag + drop in the Hotels form.

The drag + drop process looks like this:

[image]

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, on the left upper part, that is a form bound to table People.

But, the form on the right side is bound to hotels table.

So, the above shows how you can have more then one table in one form. And in 99% of such cases, those other forms will be related to the one record in the one main form.

As noted, the link master/link child settings have to be setup for the relationships to work.

So, again, with the main People form in design mode, then we set the link master and link child fields.

[image]

Keep in mind it can be a bit difficult to select the sub form control, and not select the sub form. So, just click one time on the upper left of the form, and only one click. (If you fail to do this, you will get the property sheet for the sub form "form", and you don't want that. So, one click here:

[image]

So, use of sub-forms will very much follow and "mirror" your data model. In most cases this means the sub form will display a child record of the one parent record.

The end result is sections of your form, and with sub forms, then you are able to display different table data in the one form.

Answer (score 0):

If subforms is not what you want and you are capable of writing VBA code, you can have the form unbound to any table or query. You just need a "Save"-button which starts a VBA procedure to read the data of each field and save it where you want it.

Code could look like this for two fields of your form:

```
    currentdb.execute "INSERT INTO mytable (myFiel1, myField2) SELECT '" _
        & myFormField1 & "','" & myFormField2 & "';",dbFailOnError
```

This is the most flexible way but also with the highest possibility to implement errors.